# Passing a variable into dynamic object creation in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to create multiple chartviews dynamically in QML. The chartviews are added to a gridview when created but I'm having an issue with the creation of the lineseries.

My code is

```
CustomButton
{
    id:addSeriesChartButton
    text: "Add Series"
    onClicked: {


        var name = chartsModel.get(chartSelector.currentIndex).name
        var chart = mGridViewId.getTopDelegateInstance().children[0];
        var index = chartSelector.currentIndex  // Combobox of different charts

        var axisX = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtCharts 2.15;
                                        DateTimeAxis {
                                        min:  new Date(dataManager.dataModel[index].xMin)
                                        max:  new Date(dataManager.dataModel[index].xMax)
                                            format: "hh:mm:ss:zzz"
                                        }', chart, {index: index});

        var axisY = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtCharts 2.15;
                                        ValueAxis {
                                            min: gLinkMin
                                            max: gLinkMax }', chart);

        var mapper = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtCharts 2.15;
                        VXYModelMapper {
                            firstRow: 1
                            xColumn : 0
                            yColumn: 1
                           model: dataManager.dataModel[index]}', chart, {index: index});

        var line = chart.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeLine, name, axisX, axisY);
        line.useOpenGL = true
        mapper.series = line;

    }
}
```

My Issue is I can't seem to pass index into the creation of axisX and mapper. This returns an error "TypeError: Passing incompatible arguments to C++ functions from Javascript is not allowed". If I pass chartSelector.currentIndex, this works, however, when I change the index of the combobox, all existing chartviews update the lineseries with the new index. I don't want this to happen. I simply just want a chartview that exists as is at the time of creation.  I can;t seem to find any reference on how to pass this value. Or even if this is the right approach. I'm assuming the  `index` won't subsequently change. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using dynamic object creation, consider using `Loader`, `setSource`, and data-uri. Here's a generic example, sorry, I haven't adapted it for QtCharts:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    id: page
    Repeater {
        model: [ 
            { qml: "Rectangle { }",
              obj: { width: 100,
                     height: 100,
                     color: "red" } },
            { qml: "Rectangle { radius: height * 0.5 }",
              obj: { width: 50,
                     height: 50,
                     color: "orange" } },
            { qml: "Button { }",
              obj: { text: "Click Me" } }
        ]
        delegate: Loader {
            x: Math.random() * page.width
            y: Math.random() * page.height
            Component.onCompleted: setSource(
                `data:text/plain,import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
` + modelData.qml,
                 modelData.obj
            );            
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADJ3icjVLBTsMwDL33K6yeNpjKOOwSbowjk9g4IqSFxmoDaVwyVwxN/XfcdRQKbOWd4vjFeX62LUoKDEteVjZ9iWwvTObkOZDbRHc6Q9hFILBGQSnhPlhhiZoxHHINCjLoFDxAd9NgB6+F3MYrTFn7zEk1qONJjwNAT89KEm/WcK7gcjr9STggR5vlfIqRkqMg/wU0MdRQTwbVBG1stVGH2nAG02Q2KHE2pPAo4VMgBRGAJzReV8zkT9nFuJWf4rmTkcGirdUxH7uTjAUzGZaCW9KmN7MGWwULzXkiegwVo7E40Iw52XfaY74fYbY996hzkoXy6Dkh35wdMsr+bJDvqQopjn6ZszaatWpauiidtn5i/7ehazhvV+9G3idi3R++f+XFuV56fPU96lKtjXVUfwAHK8tc)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually ended up doing something like this:

```
CustomButton
{
    id:addSeriesChartButton
    text: "Add Series"
    onClicked: {


        var name = chartsModel.get(chartSelector.currentIndex).name
        var chart = mGridViewId.getTopDelegateInstance().children[0];
        var index = chartSelector.currentIndex  // Combobox of different charts

        var axisX = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtCharts 2.15;
                                        DateTimeAxis {
                                        min:  new Date(dataManager.dataModel[' + index + '].xMin)
                                        max:  new Date(dataManager.dataModel[' + index + '].xMax)
                                            format: "hh:mm:ss:zzz"
                                        }', chart, {index: index});

        var axisY = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtCharts 2.15;
                                        ValueAxis {
                                            min: gLinkMin
                                            max: gLinkMax }', chart);

        var mapper = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtCharts 2.15;
                        VXYModelMapper {
                            firstRow: 1
                            xColumn : 0
                            yColumn: 1
                           model: dataManager.dataModel[' + index + ']}', chart, {index: index});

        var line = chart.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeLine, name, axisX, axisY);
        line.useOpenGL = true
        mapper.series = line;

    }
}
```

Seemed to fix it